# How to deploy only the delta changes for ADF in different environments?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-artifacts

I'm implementing CICD for Azure Datafactory which will deploy only the delta changes on that ADF in different environments.

Wanted to know the usage of PartialArmTemplates folder generated by the adf_publish branch. Is there any way to deploy ADF with the use of PartialArmTemplates using the task "Azure Resource Group Deployment"?

Or, is there any way to deploy the **delta changes** for the ADF in different environments?

Comment: ARM templates are idempotent. Any updates to the ARM templates will result in delta deployments by definition. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When the ADF is published from the visual editor, it is going to deploy the delta changes only. But I am implementing CICD with Azure DevOps and using the task "Azure Resource Group Deployment" which is taking the below two files as input:ARMTemplateForFactory.json and ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json. Now my question is, whether the task is deploying the delta changes or not? Because, the template consists of the whole ADF each time I am deploying.

Comment: See my previous comment. ARM template deployments are **always** deltas.